# Jquery ID Selectors not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have a bunch of HTML with tags like this:

```
<div id="Field~1">Text text</div>
```

I can't use normal ID selectors like:

```
alert($("#Field~1").text())
```

I'm guessing it's something to do with the "~" but is it possible to reference these type still?

I have setup a JSfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/4M97c/

Comment: The `~` is also called the [next siblings selector](http://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to escape all occurence special character in selectors with `\\`.

**First Approach:**

```
 alert($("#Field\\~1").text())
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4M97c/2/)**

**Second Approach:**

```
var ID="Field~1";
alert($("[id='"+ID+"']").text())
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4M97c/4/)**

Comment: Please don't use the second approach :)

Answer (score 6):

You need to escape special character `~` with double backslashes `\\`. From the **[docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)**:

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as 
>   !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must
>   be escaped with with two backslashes: \\

```
alert($("#Field\\~1").text())
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4M97c/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Arguably the easiest (and best performing) way to deal with special characters in an identifier is to use [`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById) and wrap it inside a jQuery object.

```
alert($(document.getElementById('Field~1')).text());
```

Besides selectors, the `$()` also accepts a DOM element and turns it into a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

just do this:

```
alert($('[id="Field~1"]').text())
```

---

This is a string representation of id so you don't have to worry about escaping special characters.

Comment: This will not use `document.getElementById()` though.

Comment: The selector you're using there inspects *all* elements on the page and checks if any of them has an attribute `id` with value `Field~1`; that's far from being efficient.